# Broadcast operation over rows of 3D tensor (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor p of dimension [BATCH_SIZE, 128], and tensors A, B both of dimension [528, 128]. I would like to build a new tensor p' of size [BATCH_SIZE, 528] where column j is defined as:

```
tf.reduce_prod(self.A[j,:] * p + self.B[j,:], axis=1)
```

I currently have a brute-force implementation of this using a `for` loop, but it's *very* slow. Is there any way I can use broadcasting or something to speed this up?

```
ps = []
for j in xrange(self.A.shape[0]):
    a = self.A[j,:]
    b = self.B[j,:]
    ps.append(tf.reduce_prod(a * p + b, axis=1))
p = tf.stack(ps, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = tf.reduce_prod(self.A * p[:, tf.newaxis] + self.B, axis=2)
```